# FishEye lens calibration with OpenCv 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv

I have to calibrate my camera with a Fisheye lens.

First I used OpenCv 2.4 with the flag CV_CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL to get better results but it wasn't enough.
After, I have seen that OpenCv 3.0 have fisheye function for calibration.

I compute my objectPoints and get my imagePoints with findChessboardCorners(), they seem correct.

My problem is after, with **fisheye::calibrate**. 
My returned values such as reprojection error, intrinsic matrix and distorted coefficients are wrong. They are -nan values.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: Same here. Any progress in that?

Answer (score 3):

For new OpenCV 3.0 fisheye functions, I found I did not get a usable intrinsic calibration unless `cv::fisheye::CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC` flag was specified (e.g. 38 pixel reprojection error).  Also, I was specifying `cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_SKEW`.  Of course, you should specify as many `cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_Kx` flags as you can.

For my lens, which is a very simple, miniature lens but with big radial distortion, the normal OpenCV rectification functions did not yield accurate rectifications.  I was able to get good results with the above flags and fixing `K2=K3=K4=0`.

Comment: Is it possible to see your code? I can not find a fisheye camera calibration tutorial.

Comment: @artoon: There is hardly any code to show.  It is just a one-line function call to `cv::fisheye::calibrate`.  I found the parameters to be obvious as they are almost the same as the regular `cv::calibrateCamera` function, except there is a different set of flags.  It is pretty much a drop-in replacement.  (Note I used default parameters for termination criteria parameter).

If you are not familiar with the `cv::calibrateCamera` function either, I suggest reading some of the many OpenCV camera calibration tutorials/samples out there.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about how fixing K parameters effect the calibration? My rectification is so bad on fisheye stereos..